# Pass lambda as argument

Tags: c#

I have two methods where the only difference is one lambda predicate:

```
public static double LowerQuartile(this IOrderedEnumerable<double> list)
{
    var median = list.Median();
    var elements = list.Where(x => x < median).ToList();
    if (!list.Contains(median))
        elements.Add(median);

    return elements.OrderBy(x => x).Median();
}

public static double UpperQuartile(this IOrderedEnumerable<double> list)
{
    var median = list.Median();
    var elements = list.Where(x => x > median).ToList();
    if (!list.Contains(median))
        elements.Add(median);

    return elements.OrderBy(x => x).Median();
}
```

So I want to join them and pass a lambda as parameter. I tried with something like this:

```
public static double CalculateQuartile(IOrderedEnumerable<double> list, Expression<Func<IOrderedEnumerable<double>,bool>> predicate)
{
    var median = list.Median();
    var elements = list.Where(predicate).ToList();
    if (!list.Contains(median))
        elements.Add(median);

    return elements.OrderBy(x => x).Median();
}
```

But it doesn't work. How could I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be something like this

```
public static double Quartile(this IOrderedEnumerable<double> list,
                              Func<double,double,bool> predicate)
{
    var median = list.Median();
    var elements = list.Where(x=>predicate(x,median)).ToList();
    if (!list.Contains(median))
        elements.Add(median);

    return elements.OrderBy(x => x).Median();
}
```

and you can use as

```
var val = list.Quartile((x, y) => x > y);
```

Answer (score 2):

The lambdas `x => x < median` and `x => x > median` are both of the type `Func<double, bool>`. As you do have the `median` as another variable inside, you will have to accept that as a parameter too, so you would end up with `Func<double, double, bool>`:

```
public static double CalculateQuartile(this IOrderedEnumerable<double> list,
        Func<double, double, bool> predicate)
{ … }
```

You *could* do it as an expression and paste in the reference to `median` at run-time, but I would suggest against it.

Instead, I would recommend you to solve this in a way, where the user of your function does not need to specify the correct lambda for it to work. After all, you just have two cases: upper quartile and lower quartile. So you might simply want to have a boolean flag as a parameter instead which allows you to choose between lower an upper quartile:

```
public static double CalculateQuartile(this IOrderedEnumerable<double> list,
        bool calculateUpperQuartile = false)
{
    var median = list.Median();
    var predicate = calculateUpperQuartile ? (x => x > median) : (x => x < median);
    var elements = list.Where(predicate).ToList();
    if (!list.Contains(median))
        elements.Add(median);

    return elements.OrderBy(x => x).Median();
}
```

To make it more usable by the user, I would still offer both a `CalculateUpperQuartile` and `CalculateLowerQuartile` function though—but of course, you can internally use a single implementation to handle both.

Comment: Honestly I will join your and L.B. answer and I will keep both methods CalculateUpperQuartile and CalculateLowerQuartile but they will use third method and pass the predicate , this way end user still has possibility to chose.